# What tools exist for capturing consecutive screenshots of a film?

Tags: screenshot, screen-capture, film

Is there any tools that allow for capturing screenshots of a film at set intervals? E.g. something that captures a screenshot every second and saves them to files in an ordered sequence. I'm using Windows, but I'm open for Linux suggestions as well.

Comment: Are you on Windows, Mac, or some flavor of Linux?

Comment: Also what format is the film in?

Comment: @StevenH I'm on Windows, I fortgot to mention that. I will update the post. The format doesn't matter, I'll just convert to that which works.

Comment: You use the term "Screenshot". Are you wanting to capture the whole screen of the computer the video is playing on or are you wanting just frames of the video?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Preferably the frames of the video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily be done via [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/), the [documentation describes the process](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion)

> For extracting images from a video:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i foo.avi -r 1 -s WxH -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg
> ```
>
> This will extract one video frame per second from the video and will
>   output them in files named `foo-001.jpeg`, `foo-002.jpeg`, etc. Images
>   will be rescaled to fit the new WxH values.
>
> If you want to extract just a limited number of frames, you can use
>   the above command in combination with the -vframes or -t option, or in
>   combination with -ss to start extracting from a certain point in time.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. And a quick tip to everyone: don't attempt to run ffmpeg with PowerShell. Use cmd and save yourself a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [AutoScreenShot](http://www.theuds.com/autoscreenshot.php?lang=EN) will do what you need.